# BibLaTeX/BibTeX custom field to show file link

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, hyperref

I am trying to build a database for my references. I don't want to use Mendeley or so to do the job. Therefore I have a pdf file that displays all references that I have, like it is in the MWE. Now I want to add a custom field called `file` to replace the `note` field, so that I can open the file by clicking in the link. For now I am using BibLaTeX, but I would like it to work with regular BibTeX (if possible). That field can be added to any entry in the database and when displayed shall appear at very end (if possible).

```
\documentclass[%
    a4paper,
    english,
    11pt,
]{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Padial:2010,
    title={The integrative future of taxonomy},
    author={José M.~Padial and Aurélien Miralles and Ignacio De la Riva and Miguel Vences},
    journal={Frontiers in Zoology},
    year=2010,
    month=may,
    volume=7,
    number=16,
    pages={1--14},
    doi={10.1186/1742-9994-7-16},
    issn={1742-9994},
    note={\href{file:./article/2010_Padial.pdf}{Open file}},
    keywords={biology, taxonomy},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\newif\ifBIBLATEX
\BIBLATEXtrue % or
%\BIBLATEXfalse

\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{type1ec}
%\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage[%
    colorlinks,
    unicode,
    breaklinks,
]{hyperref}

\usepackage[strict,autostyle]{csquotes}

\ifBIBLATEX % use BibLaTeX

    \usepackage[%
        backend=bibtex,
        style=ieee,
    ]{biblatex}
    \DeclareRangeChars{~,;-+/{}} % add '{}' as page range delimiter
    \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\else % use regular BibTeX

    \usepackage[noadjust]{cite} % cite without adjusting
    \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran} % IEEE style for BibTeX

\fi

\usepackage[left=5cm,right=2cm,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage[color,notref,notcite]{showkeys}


\begin{document}

\nocite{*} % list all entries

\ifBIBLATEX % use BibLaTeX

    \printbibliography
    %\printbibliography[keyword=taxonomy]

\else % use regular BibTeX

    \bibliography{\jobname}

\fi

\end{document}
```

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111846/biblatex-2-custom-fields-only-one-is-working.