# Biblatex: 2 custom fields, only one is working

Tags: biblatex, biber

Following this question [BibLaTeX/BibTeX custom field to show file link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111756/biblatex-bibtex-custom-field-to-show-file-link) and [Notes after bibliography entry with Biber and biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83024/notes-after-bibliography-entry-with-biber-and-biblatex) I get it to work (well, more or less). In the code below I defined a field `file` and `mynote`. It is working for `file` but not for `mynote`. I don't understand why!

```
\documentclass[%
    a4paper,
    english,
    11pt,
]{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Padial:2010,
    title={The integrative future of taxonomy},
    author={José M.~Padial and Aurélien Miralles and Ignacio De la Riva and Miguel Vences},
    journal={Frontiers in Zoology},
    year=2010,
    month=may,
    volume=7,
    number=16,
    pages={1--14},
    doi={10.1186/1742-9994-7-16},
    issn={1742-9994},
    mynote={Very good book!},
    file={./article/2010_Wang.pdf},
    keywords={biology, taxonomy},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{type1ec}
%\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage[%
    left=5cm,
    right=2cm,
    %showframe,
    ]{geometry}

\usepackage[color,notref,notcite]{showkeys}

\usepackage[strict,autostyle]{csquotes}

\usepackage[%
    backend=biber,
    style=ieee,
]{biblatex}
\DeclareRangeChars{~,;-+/{}} % add '{}' as page range delimiter
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{mynote}{\textbf{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{file}{\href{file:#1}{\textbf{Open file}}}
\AtEveryBibitem{%
    \csappto{blx@bbx@\thefield{entrytype}}{% put at end of entry
        \iffieldundef{file}{\space \textbf{No file!}}{%
        \space \printfield{file}}
        \iffieldundef{mynote}{\space \textbf{No annotation!}}{\space\printfield{mynote}}
    }
}

\usepackage[%
    colorlinks,
    unicode,
    breaklinks,
]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*} % list all entries

\printbibliography
%\printbibliography[keyword=taxonomy]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is because `file` is already a field to biblatex, although one not used by the standard styles, while `mynote` isn't. You must remap (via `DeclareSourcemap`) the `mynote` field to one of the `user[a-f]` fields before you can use them.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Padial:2010,
    title={The integrative future of taxonomy},
    author={José M.~Padial and Aurélien Miralles and Ignacio De la Riva and Miguel Vences},
    journal={Frontiers in Zoology},
    year=2010,
    month=may,
    volume=7,
    number=16,
    pages={1--14},
    doi={10.1186/1742-9994-7-16},
    issn={1742-9994},
    mynote={Very good book!},
    file={./article/2010_Wang.pdf},
    keywords={biology, taxonomy},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[color,notref,notcite]{showkeys}

\usepackage[%
    backend=biber,
    style=ieee,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareRangeChars{~,;-+/{}} % add '{}' as page range delimiter

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{file}{\href{file:#1}{\textbf{Open file}}}

\AtEveryBibitem{%
    \csappto{blx@bbx@\thefield{entrytype}}{% put at end of entry
        \iffieldundef{file}{\space \textbf{No file!}}{%
        \space \printfield{file}
      }
    }
  }

\DeclareSourcemap{
    \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
      \map{
        \step[fieldsource=mynote]
        \step[fieldset=usera,origfieldval]
    }
  }
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{usera}{\textbf{#1}}

\AtEveryBibitem{%
    \csappto{blx@bbx@\thefield{entrytype}}{% put at end of entry
        \iffieldundef{usera}{%
          \space \textbf{No annotation!}}{%
          \space\printfield{usera}
        }
    }
}

\usepackage[%
    colorlinks,
    unicode,
    breaklinks,
]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*} % list all entries

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very good answer. In the end I used the field `annotation` (as it is already defined in BibLaTeX) and did as I had done for `file`.

Comment: If so, you should consider changing your database to reflect this (specially since your use of `mynote` seems to fall into the purpose of `annotation`). I must say that IMHO, while this answer works fine and is a good approach to single files, Guido's answer seems to me to be the "right" one to choose, since it approaches the subject in a more generalized way.

Comment: This is the only answer I could get to work. It's perhaps good to emphasize that the field can *only* be mapped to user[a-f], and not another name of your choosing.

Comment: @StefanvanderWalt, Actually you *do* can create new, custom fields by playing with the data models (see §4.5.3 of the [manual](//texdoc.net/pkg/biblatex)) instead of remapping it to the official custom ones (`user[a-f]` etc.). There were a typo in Guido's answer (`filed` instead of `field`). Perhaps if you try now? I just ran it with my MWE, only changing where I used `usera` to the new `mynote` field with no apparent problem. I insist that his is the correct answer because it addresses more general usage and makes use of the full power of biblatex+biber.

Answer (score 12):

Biblatex offers builtin support for  the `file` field (even if it is not a standard one). Users can extend the data model by creating new fields, but they have to be declared in configuration files According to the manual (page 175) they are ordered as follows:

```
blx-dm.def→
‘datamodel option’.dbx →
‘style option’.dbx →
‘citestyle option’.dbx and ‘bibstyle option’.dbx →
biblatex-dm.cfg
```

Thus, you can create a `biblatex-dm.cfg`  file in the working directory and use

```
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=literal, skipout=false]{mynote}
```

The creation of file can be done within your file using `filecontents` package and

```
\begin{filecontents}{biblatex-dm.cfg}
    \DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=literal, skipout=false]{mynote}
\end{filecontents}
```

Comment: Just a couple of comments - you can omit `skipout=false` as this is the default. Also, you need `\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{mynote}` too. This declares "mynote" as valid for all entrytypes and the macro you mentioned defines its type.

Comment: Indeed `skipout=false` can be omitted.  For `\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields` apparently it is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I noticed, probably it is obvious but I was missing it, is that the datamodel definitions must precede biblatex loading. The order that works fine is:

1. Use package filecontents:

```
\usepackage{filecontents}
```

2. Detail the 'biblatex-dm.cfg' required content

```
\begin{filecontents}{biblatex-dm.cfg}
    \DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=literal, skipout=false]{mynote}
    DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{mynote}
\end{filecontents}
```

3. Load the biblatex with options:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee,sorting=none]{biblatex}
```

Many thanks to all for the question and for the answers!
I was really surprised how powerful biblatex became.