# Extend data model to allow for custom fields with biber in tool mode

Tags: biblatex, biber

I want to extend `biber`'s data model, i.e. I want `biber` to accept fields such as `review` or `owner` as valid entry fields for all entry types.

<sup>(Note: This is *not* about using data from these fields in a document, nor do I want to [map custom fields to existing fields](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111851/37118) such as `usera` or `customa`. Please see below ("Background") if you wonder why I'm asking this.)</sup>

Using `biber` in tool mode, I extended the default configuration file (found with `biber --tool-conf`) in the following way:

```xml
<config>
<!-- skipped 383 lines -->
  <datamodel>
    <!-- skipped "constants" and "entrytypes" --> 
    <fields>
      <!-- skipped all predefined fields --> 
      <field fieldtype="field" datatype="literal">owner</field>
      <field fieldtype="field" datatype="literal">review</field>
    </fields>
    <entryfields>
      <field>owner</field>
      <field>review</field>
    <!-- skipped remainder of file -->
    </entryfields>
  </datamodel>
</config>
```

I [uploaded the full modified `biber.conf` to pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/QACDf8kR).

As far as I can see, this "works", i.e. running `biber --tool input.bib` with this `input.bib`

```
@REPORT{Self2016,
  YEAR      = {2016},
  AUTHOR    = {Self, My},
  TITLE     = {The title},
  OWNER     = {Me},
  REVIEW    = {Important stuff.}
}
```

does not delete the `review` and `owner` fields with the modified configuration file (whereas the default configuration deletes these fields).

**My Question is:** *Why* does this work? I found this solution more or less by trial and error. I suppose that adding the `<field ...>` in `<fields>` tells `biber` that such a field *may* exist. Actually, this extension of the configuration alone is functional. I further assume that the entry under `<entryfields>` makes the new field a valid field for *all* entry types. If I skip this part, `biber` complains when I call it with `--validate-datamodel`.

Could you please tell me if my assumptions are correct and help me to understand where this can be found in the [biber](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/biblio/biber/documentation/biber.pdf) or [biblatex](http://mirror.unicorncloud.org/CTAN/macros/latex/exptl/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) manual? I think §4.5.4 in the `biblatex` manual is quite relevant, but is there any documentation on how the LaTeX commands documented there are related to the XML structure in `biber.conf`?

Besides, is this the correct way to extend the data model or did I do it terribly wrong but the test case is too simple to reveal this?

---

*Background*: I use JabRef to manage my references. Sometimes, I use JabRef's "Review" tab to annotate an entry. These notes are saved in the `review` field of the respective entry. From time to time, I run `biber` in tool mode on the BIB file, in order to get clean formatting, sorting and apply some other transformations. This worked well in the past, but as of biber 2.6, biber discards custom entry fields. This is what I reported [here on Github](https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/146) where @plk advised me to extend the data model.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are correct in your assumptions. The field elements  describe allowable fields. Biber uses this to decide whether to allow the field. Other aspects of the datamodel are used for validation. The `.conf` file datamodel format is not really documented because people rarely use custom datamodels in tool mode. The biblatex macros for datamodel manipulation write the XML you see to the `.bcf` file (but with a `bcf:` namespace).

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem, and I really didn't want to maintain my own version of the Biber config file.
I noticed that in the default data model there are the many fields defined which I never use, including `usera`, `userb` etc. and `lista`, `listb` etc. So my workaround is to rename my custom fields (in this case fields starting with `OPT`, which I want to preserve) to these pre-defined fields, run Biber in tool mode, then rename them back. Here's a little Bash script which does this:

```bash
# Define replacements (each will be prefixed with 'OPT')
FIND=(address booktitle doi   editor isbn  issn  location month note  url)
REPL=(usera   userb     userc userd  usere userf lista    listb listc listd)
IXS=`seq 0 $((${#FIND[*]} - 1))`

# Input and output file
FILE=refs.bib

# Replace forward
for i in $IXS; do
  sed -i '' s/OPT${FIND[$i]}/${REPL[$i]}/ $FILE
done

# Biber
biber --tool --output-file=$FILE $FILE

# Replace back
for i in $IXS; do
  sed -i '' s/${REPL[$i]}/OPT${FIND[$i]}/ $FILE
done
```