# Add custom fields to biber data modell

Tags: biber

**EDITED to make the question more clear**

I have the same desire, as the original poster of this  [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/333794/120477).

I was also able, to add my desired fields to `biber`s data modell and voila: running `biber --tool` does not yield a warning on my additional fields any more.  So far so good.

As described in that self answering question, I copied the data model file from `biber` (i.e. `biber --tool-config`) and added my fields.

```xml
<config>
<!-- skipped 383 lines -->
  <datamodel>
    <!-- skipped "constants" and "entrytypes" --> 
    <fields>
      <!-- skipped all predefined fields --> 
      <field fieldtype="field" datatype="literal">source</field>
      <field fieldtype="field" datatype="literal">copyright</field>
    </fields>
    <entryfields>
      <field>source</field>
      <field>copyright</field>
    <!-- skipped remainder of file -->
    </entryfields>
  </datamodel>
</config>
```

Now my question: is there any chance, to write my custom fields to an additional date model config file, so that it enhances whatever data model will be used by future versions of `biber`?

Chapter 3.1.2 describes, that `biber` uses "user-level maps", which could be declared by a LaTeX command or in a config file.  The manual states, that the `sourcemap` option could be used, to "Add new fields to an entry", which is exactly my desire.

This would be the best solution.  It would ensure, that the default data model in its latest revision, will always be loaded as default model and by additionally loading my fields via a second, additional config file, all fields are available.  I don't have to check regularly, if the `biber` team updated the data model and thus have to insert also the recent changes into my enhanced and file.

What content must be defined in a file to be loaded with the `--sourcemap=<extension-config>` to extend the default data map with my custom fields?

Comment: This answer is probably what you want: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/415630/105447

Comment: @gusbrs This is the same solution, I was able to realize: copy the complete data model, insert the missing fields, run the ``biber --tool`` with the manipulated data model.  BUT: when the biber authors change the biber data model, I have to update my enhanced file.  What I want: define only the additional fields in an config file.  When ``biber`` is run in tool mode, it will read its default data model and than will add my extra definitions to it.  Therefore, I always use the most recent version of the data model and requested config file adds only those fields, which are missing.

Comment: Mhm, I might be wrong but, as far as I recall, that's something which is not possible at the biber config file level, which is probably the only viable method for `biber --tool`.

Comment: @gusbrs That would be no so nice.

Comment: @gusbrs if that is the case, I should create a script, which regularly diffs the actual data set config file with the one, I was using today.  If there is a diff, it should at least send some kind of warning and the differences it found.

Comment: Jan, I'm really not sure, let's see if someone more knowledgeable drops by. But I said so, because at the time I answered that one, I did some research, and I wouldn't go with "copying the whole thing then modifying" if there were an alternative. I agree with you it is not ideal to have to do so. On the other hand, the data model should be pretty stable, and you can always get your diff directly from the repo: https://github.com/plk/biber/commits/dev/data/biber-tool.conf.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to put the entire data model in the config file, only additions or changes. See the chapter "The Data Model" in the `biber` documentation: https://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/files/biblatex-biber/current/documentation/biber.pdf/download

For example, from 3.13 in the above document, to add a `director` field to `video` entrytypes, put just the following in the `biber` config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <datamodel>
    <fields>
      <field fieldtype="list" datatype="name">director</field>
    </fields>
    <entryfields>
      <entrytype>video</entrytype>
      <field>director</field>
    </entryfields>
  </datamodel>
</config>
```

Comment: Could you please give a short example?

Comment: PLK, Ah, you dropped by. :) I didn't know that, thanks!