# Display BibTeX specific fields in LaTeX

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies

Suppose that I have a .bib file as follows

```
@book{latexcompanion,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The \LaTeX\ Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts",
}
```

Can I write something like

```
A well-known {\LaTeX} book~\cite{latexcompanion}
is published by \bibfield{latexcompanion}{publisher}.
```

where the hypothetical `bibfield` macro would insert the `publisher` field of the `latexcompanion` entry ("Addison-Wesley" in this case)?

Comment: See also [How to extract BibTeX entries (as DOI, abstract, etc.)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/207591/35864)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `biblatex` packages has low-level commands that offer this functionality (see Section 3.8.7 of the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)). I want to try giving a general solution, especially for the `publisher` field you need to use.

## Find out the data type of the needed field

In Section 2.2.2 of the biblatex manual, there is a list of pre-defined data fields and their respective type. From the list, we see that `publisher` is a list.

## Use the corresponding low level cite command for the data type

Since `publisher` is a list, we use the corresponding `\citelist` command. (For example, for `date` we would use `\citefield`, since it is a field.)

Our code building on your MWE becomes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\begin{document}
     \citelist{latexcompanion}{publisher}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I cite custom fields with this? If I add a field `chaptercount` to the `.bib`, I get `'chaptercount' undefined or not a field` when I use `\citefield`.

Comment: This worked for me for custom fields: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111851/16069